# Support for parsing a certificate file in ballerina

Tags: cryptography, ssl-certificate, ballerina

I need to read the content of a `.cert` format file. In java, we can do this as below.

```java
CertificateFactory fac = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("\\path\\to\\file\\cert.crt");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) fac.generateCertificate(is);
System.out.println("From: " + cert.getNotBefore());
System.out.println("Until: " + cert.getNotAfter());
```

I need to know that, whether it's possible to do something like this using pure ballerina. (without using java interop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `ballerina/crypto` module for this.

For example:

```php
crypto:PublicKey pubKey = check crypto:decodeRsaPublicKeyFromCertFile("path/to/cert.cert");
io:println(pubKey.certificate?.notBefore);
io:println(pubKey.certificate?.issuer);
```

Related API docs: https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/crypto/latest#decodeRsaPublicKeyFromCertFile